# Python: Rolling multi-sided dice not appending to list

Tags: python, list, while-loop, append, dice

I am trying to create a system that will roll different multi-sided dice in different quantities to determine the effect adding more dice has to the chances of getting the highest number.

```
import random
from statistics import mean

#define the dice
class Dice:
    """these are the dice to roll"""
    def __init__(d, qty, sides):
        d.qty = qty
        d.sides = sides


q1d4 = Dice(1, 4)
q2d4 = Dice(2, 4)
q3d4 = Dice(3, 4)
q4d4 = Dice(4, 4)
#...removed extras for clarity
q5d20 = Dice(5, 20)
q6d20 = Dice(6, 20)

def Roll(Dice):

    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        single_rolls = []
        highest_of_rolls = []
        avg_of_highest = []
        qty = Dice.qty
        sides = Dice.sides
```

At this line I am able to successfully roll a random number between 1 and the number of sides, and it appends to the list single_rolls and this is shown in the print statement:

```
        for q in range(qty):
            #rolls a single dice "qty" times and appends the result to single_rolls
            single_rolls.append(random.randint(1, sides))
            print(single_rolls)
```

I then am trying to append just the highest number from the single_rolls list to the highest_of_rolls list within the while loop for each iteration of rolls, and then averaging it:

```
        highest_of_rolls.append(max(single_rolls))
        print(highest_of_rolls)
        i += 1

    avg_of_highest = mean(highest_of_rolls)
    print(avg_of_highest)
```

It doesn't seem to be appending to the highest_of_rolls list when I run it though. From the print statement it seems to be successfully finding the highest number from the two rolls, but the highest_of_rolls list does not seem to be growing like I would expect.

Finally at the end of the code the average is always just the last value that would have gone into highest_of_rolls and not anywhere near an average.

Here is an example of the output that seems suspicious:

```
>>> Roll(q2d20)
[11]
[11, 14]
[14]
[15]
[15, 1]
[15]
[4]
[4, 9]
[9]
[15]
[15, 2]
[15]
[1]
[1, 16]
[16]
[9]
[9, 3]
[9]
[18]
[18, 9]
[18]
[20]
[20, 11]
[20]
[13]
[13, 5]
[13]
[20]
[20, 10]
[20]
20
```

Even my simple understanding of statistics can see that 20 is not the average of multiple numbers below 20, and besides that number fluctuates wildly and is always simply the last number that would have gone into the highest_of_rolls list.

I feel like I have an indentation error somewhere, but I have tried multiple ways of writing this and it always seems to come out the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are creating a new list `[]` each loop move the variable initializations (`single_rolls = []`) before the `while` loop. You may also look into a `dict` to hold all your dice configurations, e.g. `{(n, s): Dice(n, s) for n, s in itertools.product(range(1, 5), [4, 6, 10, 20])}`

Comment: It's not the issue, but purely from an OOP perspective that seems weird. If the dice object just holds two numbers and no methods, why not pass in separate arguments to roll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is not appending to `highest_of_rolls`because in the beginning of your `while` loop you reset the variable everytime. You should define `highest_of_rolls` before the while statement, otherwise the variable will be cleared everytime you roll a dice.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yeah I had to move the variables outside of the scope and it started working like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def Roll(Dice):

i = 0
while i < 10:
    single_rolls = []
    highest_of_rolls = [] # <--- reseting highest_of_rolls to a blank list
    avg_of_highest = []
    qty = Dice.qty
    sides = Dice.sides
```

**Solution**

```
def Roll(Dice):

i = 0
highest_of_rolls = [] # <--- move outside of loop, won't erase items

while i < 10:
    single_rolls = []
    avg_of_highest = []
    qty = Dice.qty
    sides = Dice.sides
```

Also instead of using a `while i < 10:` and incrementing `i` you could use `for i in range(10)`, nothing different just eliminating the need to increment `i` for every loop.